# count the number of characters in a string

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to count the amount of times a character is repeated in a string( can be multiple words ), however, right now i think i'm pretty close to the result but my output is a bit weird:

CODE:

```
int statistics(){
  char str[122];
  int i=0;
  int count[122] = { 0 };
  printf("Enter a string: ");
  fgets(str,sizeof str, stdin);
  if(fgets(str,sizeof str, stdin) == NULL){
     printf("error");
  }
  size_t size = strlen(str);

  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      count[(int)str[i]] += 1;
}

for (i = 0; i < 122; i++) {
    if(count[i]>=1){
    printf("The %d. character has %d occurrences.\n", i, count[i]);
    }
  }
  strtok(str,"\n");
  printf("'%s' is %lu characters long\n",str,size-1);
}
```

eg input: hello

outputs:

```
The 107. character has 1 occurences.
The 198. character has 1 occurences.
The 201. character has 1 occurences.
The 205. character has 1 occurences.
The 208. character has 1 occurences.
'Hello' is 5 characters long
```

Comment: Why do you take input twice ? Remove `fgets` before `if` .

Comment: "Weird" is not precise. What is weird about it to you?

Comment: You should remove the new-line caracter with `strtok` directly after `fgets` if it succeeded. That will ensure that you use the truncated string thoughout and will make corrections such as printing `size - 1` unneccessary.

Comment: What is the output you expect? Do you want to print "The 1st char occurs 2x, the 2nd char occurs 1x" when the input is "eel"?

Comment: Although the code has many problems, it doesn't generate that output if you press (enter), type "Hello" and press (enter) again.

Comment: Also: Use `count[UCAHR_MAX+1];` and `count[(unsigned char)str[i]] += 1;`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the current encoding for the index in `count`. If your encoding is [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) (the most common encoding) then the character `'H'` has the value `72` so you will increase `count[72]` and and when you print your output you will print it as the 72:th character.

Instead use the loop variable as the counter, and then use the character in `str[i]` as the index into the counter array.

Something like this

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i)
{
    if (isprint(str[i])
    {
        printf("Character #%zu is '%c' and the count is %d\n",
               i + 1, str[i], count[str[i]]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Character #%zu is 0x%02hhx and the count is %d\n",
               i + 1, str[i], count[str[i]]);
    }
}
```

By the way, be careful with the input from [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), it will most likely leave the newline at the end of the string, and you will count that too. I handled in the code above by using [`isprint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isprint) to see if the character is "printable" or not.

Also, and more importantly, as you use the character encoding as index in the `count` array, you need as many elements in it as there are characters in the encoding. With [ASCII encoding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) (the most common and likely what you are using) you need 128 elements to count all possible characters in the [ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) (not counting "extended ASCII"). So you need to declare your `count` array with 128 elements. If you don't, then you risk indexing the `count` array out of bounds, and have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to teach people ASCII. Beyond specialized hardware devices, ASCII is seldom used. The character set and encoding used is extremely important. That almost all the currently used character sets include all of ASCII's characters and most encode them the same just leads people to falsely confirm they are using ASCII. Sure beginners can stick the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)) characters and assume they are using an encoding that is compatible with UTF-8 but they shouldn't come away thinking they are using ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your output is "weird" is that you are using `%d` to print character *code*, instead of `%c` to print the character itself:

```
printf("The '%c' (code:%d) character has %d occurrences.\n", i, i, count[i]);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/UdYPRn)

```
The 'e' (code:101) character has 1 occurrences.
The 'h' (code:104) character has 1 occurrences.
The 'l' (code:108) character has 2 occurrences.
The 'o' (code:111) character has 1 occurrences.
'hello' is 5 characters long
```

Comment: I think OP meant to print index number of the character and moreover he declared i as int

Comment: @ch3rub7 That's correct, he did declare `i` as `int`. However, his program interprets `i` as a character code when it indexes into `count`, so it's fine to pass `i` to `%c`.